# Setting node library locations via typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

In order to learn typescript and the new @Types format, I started with the [blogs from microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).  In the blog, the example is used:

```
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

You then simply have a typescript file,

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
_.padStart("Hello TypeScript!", 20, " ");
```

that you then compile and it becomes javascript that is

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var _ = require("lodash");
_.padStart("Hello TypeScript!", 20, " ");
```

However, I have found that this simple example fails to execute with an error because node.js cannot find the require("lodash"); library and throws an error.

What is the proper way to configure typescript so that it correctly references the library in the compiled javascript?

Comment: have you installed `lodash` also ?, I think you also need `lodash` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do this as of Typescript

```
$ npm install --save lodash
# This is the new bit here: 
$ npm install --save @types/lodash
```

also for `@types` can use `--save-dev` to install it only at `devDependency`

Then, in your .ts file:

Either:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Or:

```
import _ from "lodash";
```

Comment: that makes so much sense once I see it.